# whileFocus only works for <motion.input/>

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to use Framer Motion's `whileFocus` to change the scale of an item while the item is in focus. It works fine when I'm using tab to focus. However, the focus only works by clicking if I'm using the `<motion.input/>` element, not others, such as `<motion.div/>` or `<motion.button/>`.

Here is an example component with two elements, where it works for the input element, but not the div element:

```js
const MyMotionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/*whileFocus works after clicking on this input element*/}
      <motion.input
        tabIndex={0}
        className="absolute cursor-pointer bg-blue-300"
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50, x: 400, y: 200 }}
        whileFocus={{ scale: 2 }}
      />
      {/*whileFocus does not work after clicking on this div element*/}
      <motion.div
        tabIndex={0}
        className="absolute cursor-pointer bg-amber-300"
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50, x: 200, y: 200 }}
        whileFocus={{ scale: 2 }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Does anyone know how to get it going for elements such as `<motion.div/>`, or other elements that allow child elements?

Answer (score 0):

##### Possible Solution

Add `contentEditable={true}` to your `<motion.div/>`:

```js
const MyMotionComponent = () => {
  return (
      <motion.div
        ...
        whileFocus={{ scale: 2 }}
        contentEditable={true}
      />
  );
};
```

#### Solution Explained

The issue I had stems from the :focus-visible css psuedo-class that Framer Motion uses in order to determine if an element is in focus or not. The `<motion.input/>` and `<input/>` elements work with :focus-visible by default. Hence, the effects work as expected.

However, in order to get it working for some other elements (such as `<motion.div/>` and `<div/>`), the element may require the `contenteditable`/`contentEditable` attribute set to `true`.

Full example element:

```js
const MyMotionComponent = () => {
  return (
      <motion.div
        tabIndex={0}
        className="absolute cursor-pointer bg-amber-300"
        style={{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50, x: 200, y: 200}}
        whileFocus={{ scale: 2 }}
        contentEditable={true}
      />
  );
};
```